# How to remove highlight on button if IsMouseHover is true in wpf

Tags: wpf, button, highlight, selected, ismouseover

I am developing a WPF project. I want to remove highlight (it is like blue in picture) on button if isMouseHover of Button is true. And I am not sure it is called highlight. Maybe it is probably effect, focus etc.. I added BorderBrush is transparent but it didn't work. The code is as follows:

```
<Image x:Key="LoginImg" Source="..\Images\Login\oturumac.png"
       Stretch="Fill"/>
<Image x:Key="LoginImg_RollOver" Source="..\Images\Login\oturumac_rollover.png"
       Stretch="Fill"/>

<Style  x:Key="LoginButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource LoginImg_RollOver}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource LoginImg}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Picture is as follows. First picture when IsMouseOver is true:

[image]

How can I solve?

Button code is as follows:

```
 <Button Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Style="{DynamicResource LoginButtonStyle}" Click="btnLogin_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" x:Name="btnLogin" TabIndex="2"/>
```

Comment: I saw question which Sheridan mentions question but I can not solve. Because I don't select or click button. Only I drag mouse on button. And Around Button is highlight.

Comment: My apologies... I misread your question and didn't realise that it was for a `Button`. I have re-opened your question now. You'll need to show your code for the `Button` so that we can work out what you have done wrong. It seems as though you are changing the `Content` property when you really just want to change the `Background` colour?

Comment: I want to change only image. But button is highlighted. Background and BorderBrush are transparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to provide a new `ControlTemplate` for the `Button` to get rid of the default look and feel. You can just replace the default `Button ControlTemplate` with a plain `Image` control and replace your `Style Trigger`s with `ControlTemplate Trigger`s. Try this:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Name="Image" Stretch="None" 
Source="pack://application:,,,/AppName;component/Images/Login/oturumac.png" />
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Image" Property="Source" Value="
pack://application:,,,/AppName;component/Images/Login/oturumac_rollover.png" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```